# Why std::string relational operator comparison result is different for a template and a function?

Tags: c++, templates

In the following code, both the template and the function compare two strings and return which one is bigger. However, despite the same code (definition body), the result is different. Now, it might have something to do with taking a string vs string of characters (is it a C++ bug?) - but why is there a difference for a template though?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string getBiggerStr(std::string a, std::string b);

template <class T>
T getBigger(T a, T b);

int main() {
    std::cout << "\t" << getBiggerStr("Amber", "John") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\t" << getBigger("Amber", "John") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

std::string getBiggerStr(std::string a, std::string b) {
    if(a > b) return a;
    return b;
}

template <class T>
T getBigger(T a, T b) {
    if(a > b) return a;
    return b;
}
```

result:

```
        John
        Amber
```

Why is it different? Template definition body is copy pasted from function!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the arguments (and thus of the template parameter) in the `getBigger("Amber", "John")` function call is `const char*`. Thus, the comparison in that function just compares two pointers, which is *not* how to properly compare (lexicographically) two C-style strings.

In order to force the use of `std::string` as the argument/template type, you can append the [`operator ""s` suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) to the literals:

```cpp
using namespace std::string_literals;
int main() {
    std::cout << "\t" << getBiggerStr("Amber", "John") << std::endl;    // Automatic conversion to std::string
    std::cout << "\t" << getBigger("Amber"s, "John"s) << std::endl;     // Here, we need to explicitly specify
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't have a C++14-compliant compiler (required for the `operator ""s`), then you can explicitly construct two `std::string` objects as the arguments:

```cpp
std::cout << "\t" << getBigger(std::string{ "Amber" }, std::string{ "John" }) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

`getBigger("Amber", "John")` calls `getBigger<const char*>` which returns which memory address is a higher number.

Comment: It seems that declaring the strings as variables:     `std::string s1 = "Amber";
    std::string s2 = "John";` and passing them this way instead of as "" argument, fixes this "bug". Why though? [should I ask a new question or modify this one?]

Comment: @VeritAeternae because now they are `std::string`s instead of `const char *`s. String literals "abcdef" are `const char *`s (I think technically they are array references, but they decay to `const char *` in most circumstances)